# Is it possible to tell ARC to ignore just one object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

Recently converted an existing iPhone project to use ARC, and a portion of the code stopped working and kept crashing out.  It seems that ARC was automatically releasing `myRequest`:

```
ServerRequest *myRequest = [[ServerRequest alloc] init];
```

too soon, before some delegate functions had fired.

Now I know from reading up on ARC that you can set a compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` against a specific file to ignore ARC. Now that worked fine, however, I'd still quite like to use ARC. I wonder if anyone knew of a way, when you instantiate an object, to tell ARC not to manage the releasing of it, e.g.:

```
ServerRequest *myRequest = [[[ServerRequest alloc] init] ignoreARC];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning ARC off for a single variable? Not possible.

You may want to try saving myRequest in an instance variable, so ARC knows you still need it. When you're done you can release it by setting it to nil.

Answer (score 4):

You can move variables outside of ARC by using `__bridge` casts to convert the object to a `void*`, but this not the solution to your problem. You have a memory management problem, and you need to hunt it down and fix it, not band-aid it.

As @voidStern notes, if you have a request you care about keeping, you need to retain it, and then release it when you no longer care about it.

Comment: Yeah exactly I want to release it myself

Comment: In an ARC environment, this is translated: "you need to maintain a strong pointer to it, and then remove your strong pointer when you no longer care about it." Wherever you would have put "retain" assign it to an ivar. Wherever you would have put "release", clear the ivar.

Answer (score 4):

This is a really bad idea.  ARC is releasing the object because the semantics of your code don't indicate that you want to keep it.  You're trying to hide the symptom, not fix the problem.

Worse, if you managed to do what you want, you'd make your code really unmaintainable.  Some variables being managed by ARC and some not sounds like a recipe for spending all your time hunting through code trying to figure out which is which.

If you create an object and you want to hang onto it beyond the current scope, put it into an instance variable or assign it to some other object's property.